# Angular Js Data bind in input text

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind two input box **firstname** and **lastname** data in other input box **FullName** and also this box  is **readonly**

I can easily bind data in div or span but not in input box.

I have add my code Please suggest me what is best of this.

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
  $scope.student = {
   firstName : "Mahesh",
   lastName : "Parashar",
   fees : 500,
   subjects : [{
    name : 'Physics',
    marks : 70
   }, {
    name : 'Chemistry',
    marks : 80
   }, {
    name : 'Math',
    marks : 65
   }],
   fullName : function() {
    var studentObject;
    studentObject = $scope.student;
    return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
   }
  };

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Your Name</td>
            <td>
                <input name="name" ng-model="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello Greetings,</td>
            <td ng-bind="name"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>Fisrt Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lname" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Full Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lname" ng-bind="fname" />
                <span ng-bind="fname"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance
Priyanka

Comment: Please upvote answer if it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-model` to bind the value of your two input box to input box of fullname. I have made this read only by disabling it. You cannot use `ng-bind` with input boxes.

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
  $scope.student = {
   firstName : "Mahesh",
   lastName : "Parashar",
   fees : 500,
   subjects : [{
    name : 'Physics',
    marks : 70
   }, {
    name : 'Chemistry',
    marks : 80
   }, {
    name : 'Math',
    marks : 65
   }],
   fullName : function() {
    var studentObject;
    studentObject = $scope.student;
    return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
   }
  };
      $scope.$watch('student.firstName + "" + student.lastName', function(newval,oldval) {
   $scope.fullname=newval;
        

});

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Your Name</td>
            <td>
                <input name="name" ng-model="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello Greetings,</td>
            <td ng-bind="name"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>Fisrt Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="student.firstName " />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="student.lastName " ng-blur="fullname=student.fullName();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Full Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lname" ng-init="fullname=student.fullName();" ng-model="fullname" ng-disabled="true" />
                <span ng-bind="student.fullName()"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: that time I have no rights for accept answer but now I have

Comment: You can still accept the answer if it helped you. :) @PriyankaSankhala

Comment: @PriyankaSankhala I don't think its accepted as there is no green tick mark besides the answer.